# retrieve attribute in $observe function

Tags: angularjs

I was very happy coding my directive, but I needed an observer on an attribute that had to fire only if the previous value was "x". The problem is, that `$observe` doesn´t seem to provide the previous value, as `$watch` does.

Is there a fast way to access an attribute previous value, or do I have to store it for checks?

**HTML:**

```
<searcher ng-datasource = 'countries' ng-model = 'chosenCountry' placeholder = 'Search Country' ng-alias = 'country' ng-tuples = 'country as country.name' ng-rows-by-page = 2>
```

**JS**

```
app.directive("searcher", function($datasources, $document){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '?ngModel',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        }, 
        replace:true,
        template:
            "<md-select ng-attr-active = '{{hasFocus}}' ng-attr-empty = '{{!searchText}}'>"+
            "   <md-input ng-click = 'handleClick();'>"+
            "       <a class = 'fa fa-search icon' ng-if = '!searchPromise'></a>"+
            "       <a class = 'fa fa-spin icon' ng-if = 'searchPromise'>&#8987;</a>"+
            "       <input type = 'text' ng-model = 'searchText' ng-keydown = 'handleKeydown()' ng-focus='handleFocus()'>"+
            "   </md-input>"+
            "   <ul>"+
            "       <li ng-repeat = 'row in __rows track by $index' ng-click = 'choose(row)'>{{txt(row)}}</li>"+
            "   </ul>"+
            "</md-select>"+
        "",
        link: function( scope, element, attrs, ctrl ) {

....
attrs.$observe("active", function(newValue){
                if ( newValue == "false" ){
                    ctrl.$setTouched();
                }
            });
...
```

Ignored the rest of the code, as irrelevant for my question. If you want a complete, working example: http://codepen.io/sergio0983/pen/XKEQqg?editors=1010

Note that in the working example you might find slightly different code (I used the focus function to store the attribute after the first interaction) that is already working. I only want to know if I can access the previous value of the attribute in $observe somehow.

Comment: `var original = attrs.attributeName`?

Comment: Well, that very much looks like the "store it for checks", and besides, I tried it in the link function, and didn´t store it properly (got undefined) so I had to store it in the function that altered the attribute.

Comment: Provide [mcve] demo

Comment: Not sure that it´s really needed, I don´t want a piece of code that solves my issue, only want to know if there is a built in function or property in angular that makes what I want, but I will post the example if you think it may help. Will take 2 minutes.

Comment: well maybe you need to be using isolated scope...we have no idea without seeing some code

Comment: Took more than 2 minutes, but it´s done, thanks for your patience :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.$watch('someAttr',function(newValue,oldValue){
   if(oldValue === 'x'){
     // do something
   }
});
```

Comment: I´m a newbie in angular, but if I´m not wrong, $scope.$watch is used for variables in scope, and attrs.$observe for attributes in the DOM node, that is what I need, hence the question. Using $scope.$watch will always return "undefined" if you put an attribute. Not 100% sure, just correct me if I´m wrong

Comment: Exactly my case, it was an interpolated attribute; thank you for the information.